# Получить ответ от сервера, находящегося за VPN

Tags: php, post, curl, soap, wsdl

Есть cURL запрос, отправляется он по адресу 192.168.....?wsdl, находящегося на другом конце VPN-туннеля с моим сервером (там, где скрипт лежит).

Из VNC все отправляет и получает нормально. Но при запуске скрипта из браузера ответа не получаю. Я так понимаю, что браузер считает, что 192.168..... лежит в моей локальной сети.

Как можно решить такую проблему?

Comment: А VNC вы по какому адресу открываете, на тот же 192.168... ? VNC же у вас  в той подсети, вот он и видит устройства там. И от себя вы те адреса сможете увидеть только если у вас с той сетью будут разные адреса и у вас будет маршрутизация до туда через туннель

Comment: И еще надо, что бы тот удаленный сервер куда идет запрос знал, что адрес с которого вы к нему пришли находится по другую сторону туннеля и ответные пакеты вам через него слал

Comment: VNC открываю на сервере, от которого идет VPN-туннель на 192.168.0.19?wsdl. И из VNC при выполнении скрипта `# php -f /script.php > /output.txt` я получаю ответ и записываю его в output.txt.

Comment: Но мне нужно и запрос отправить из браузера и ответ получить в браузер. Вот в этом то вся проблема.

Comment: А браузер на какой машине расположен ? и как эта машина добирается до сервера ? В общем виде вы должны или открывать vpn непосредственно с той машины на которой браузер, либо ваш север надо сделать маршрутизатором, который будет передавать запросы от машины с вашем браузером дальше по туннелю. Только тут это описывать бесполезно. тонкостей много пост страниц на 20-30 с примерным описанием может выйти

Comment: Браузер находится в рандомном месте, это просто компьютер с выходом в интернет. К скрипту в браузере обращаемся по адресу ip/script.php

Comment: А как компьютер находящийся в произвольном месте интернета поймет, куда надо идти к 192.168, тем более что такие адреса в интернете не маршрутизируются. Ваш скрипт должен располагаться на сервере у которого есть реальный ip адрес или порт с маршрутизатора с реальны адресом должен быть проблрошен до сервера

Comment: Так скрипт итак находится на внешнем ip (78.40..../penalty_request.php). И вот он уже обращается через туннель к внутреннему ip другого сервера.